# CSS animation works on Safari and Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension, keyframe

The following code block runs the **animation for Firefox**

```
#rocket {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    animation-name: rocket-launch;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    -ms-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

The following part runs the animation on **Safari browser** but **not on Chrome**, all I get is a static picture corresponding to the upper **code block**.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rocketLaunch {
    0% {
        top: 700px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 10px;
    }
}
@keyframes rocketLaunch {
    0% {
        top: 700px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 10px;
    }
}
```

Why won't the animation run on Chrome ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

modify second animation-name(without prefix).

#### Before

```
-webkit-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
        animation-name: rocket-launch;
```

#### After

```
-webkit-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
        animation-name: rocketLaunch;
```

please notice difference in animation name.

also,
If you don't care about browser version(cross browser)
I would like to recommend for remove prefix.

#### Proposal

```
#rocket {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, the animation name was indeed the problem, but it was still running on Safari (even with the wrong name) any idea why ?

Comment: @JaswanthSaiVenkat Because maybe difference rendering between safari and chrome.

I guess that the chrome renderer looks for a defined keyframe. If there is no keyframe with the name declared in 'animation-name', then the rendering of 'animation-name' with '-webkit-' is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

you wrote the animation name wrongly try this code.

```
#rocket {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    -moz-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    -ms-animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    animation-name: rocketLaunch;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-duration: 5s;

}
```

Comment: Hey, the animation name was indeed the problem, but it was still running on Safari (even with the wrong name) any idea why ?

Comment: @JaswanthSaiVenkat it will work in chrome if you arrange css like this order.  
-webkit-animation-name: rocketLaunch; 
animation-name: rocket-launch; 
but its wrong you have to put unprefixed property last check my answer.Here you should change your animation name.I hope you understand.